# Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `IO Bool'

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a prime number generator and utilizing MillerRabin formula check whether or not the number is prime before it returns the number back into me. 
Here is my code below:

```
primegen :: Int -> IO Integer
primegen bits =
    fix $ \again -> do
        x <- fmap (.|. 1) $ randomRIO (2^(bits - 1), 2^bits - 1)
        if primecheck x then return x else again

primesTo100 = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]

powerMod :: (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> a -> b -> a
powerMod m _ 0 =  1
powerMod m x n | n > 0 = join (flip f (n - 1)) x `rem` m where
  f _ 0 y = y
  f a d y = g a d where
    g b i | even i    = g (b*b `rem` m) (i `quot` 2)
          | otherwise = f b (i-1) (b*y `rem` m)

witns :: (Num a, Ord a, Random a) => Int -> a -> IO [a]
witns x y = do
     g <- newStdGen 
     let r = [9080191, 4759123141, 2152302898747, 3474749600383, 341550071728321]
         fs = [[31,73],[2,7,61],[2,3,5,7,11],[2,3,5,7,11,13],[2,3,5,7,11,13,17]]
     if  y >= 341550071728321
      then return $ take x $ randomRs (2,y-1) g
       else return $ snd.head.dropWhile ((<= y).fst) $ zip r fs

primecheck :: Integer -> IO Bool
primecheck n | n `elem` primesTo100 = return True
                     | otherwise = do
    let pn = pred n
        e = uncurry (++) . second(take 1) . span even . iterate (`div` 2) $ pn
        try = return . all (\a -> let c = map (powerMod n a) e in
                                  pn `elem` c || last c == 1)
    witns 100 n >>= try
```

I don't understand whats going on with the IO Bool. And I'm getting the following error...

```
 Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `IO Bool'
 In the return type of a call of `primecheck'
 In the expression: primecheck x
 In a stmt of a 'do' block: if primecheck x then return x else again
```

If I change the IO Bool to just a normal Bool, they will give me this:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `m0 a0'
```

Thanks for the help guys! I appreciate it.

Comment: You might consider writing this in [`MonadRandom`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.8/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random.html) instead of `IO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `primecheck` returns `IO Bool`, when you call it in `primegen`, you need to sequence it rather than calling it like a pure function.

```
primegen :: Int -> IO Integer
primegen bits =
    fix $ \again -> do
        x <- fmap (.|. 1) $ randomRIO (2^(bits - 1), 2^bits - 1)
        success <- primecheck x
        if success then return x else again
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if primecheck x then return x else again
```

is not valid because `primecheck x` returns a value of type `IO Bool`.  You want to sequence the monad with do notation or something like:

```
primecheck x >>= (\val -> if val then return x else again)
```